# How to autogenerate the custom-elements.json using Storybook ad Webpack?

Tags: webpack, storybook

For my project I am trying to autogenerate the custom-elements.json that would further dispalay argTypes in Storybook with property descriptions, I have added the following code snippet into the main.js under .storybook

```
    config.plugins.push({
      apply: compiler => {
        compiler.hooks.thisCompilation.tap(
          'x',
          compilation => {
            compilation.hooks.additionalAssets.tapAsync(
              'CustomElementsJsonWebpackPlugin',
              async callback => {

                const glob = require('glob');
                const pattern = "packages/web-components/src/**/*.element.ts"
                const elementTsFilenames = glob.sync(pattern);

                // Adds the new file to the build
                compilation.assets['custom-elements.json'] = {
                  source: () => elementTsFilenames,
                  name: 'custom-elements.json',
                  size: () => elementTsFilenames.length,
                };

                callback();
              }
            )
          }
        )
      }
    })
```

But the file is not generated, could you please give me some hints what I am doing wrong, since I am very new to webpack?